# Compare values in an array and change the value

Tags: php, arrays, compare

**Hello** 
Suppose i have this array:

```
    array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 123,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 1',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-10',
    'plan' => 'B/B',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 456,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 2',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 1',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-07',
    'plan' => 'H/B',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 123,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 1',
    'start_date' => '2018-01-05',
    'end_date' => '2017-02-12',
    'plan' => 'H/B',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 666,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 3',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 3',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-30',
    'plan' => 'B/B',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 123,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 3',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-30',
    'plan' => 'B/B',
  ),
)
```

i need to run through array and check forech var in array if his hotel_id and his deal_name is the same i want to add 99 to hotel_id for example this array should look like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 12399,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 1',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-10',
    'plan' => 'B/B',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 456,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 2',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 1',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-07',
    'plan' => 'H/B',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 12399,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 1',
    'start_date' => '2018-01-05',
    'end_date' => '2017-02-12',
    'plan' => 'H/B',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 666,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 3',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 3',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-30',
    'plan' => 'B/B',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'hotel_id' => 123,
    'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
    'deal_name' => 'deal 3',
    'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
    'end_date' => '2017-12-30',
    'plan' => 'B/B',
  ),
)
```

Because the array[0] and array[2] have the same hotel_id and the same deal_name
but array[4] have only the same hotel_id and not same feal_name.

this is a dynamic array so it can contain lots of data.
Of course there could be another hotel_id with the same deals.

Please any help?

Comment: From where 12399 comes?

Comment: i need to add 99 to the hotel_id the second array is what i need to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, then there are two subtasks.
1) Find records with identical pairs "hotel_id and deal_name". 
2) Then change their hotel_id.

My decision: for the first pass on the entire array, we will collect information about the hotel_id and deal_name. To save it, I use a multidimensional array.

This array will contain data

```
{
  "123": { // hotel_id
    "deal 1": [ // hotel_name
      0,  // keys with this hotel_id and hotel_name
      2
    ],
    "deal 3": [
      4
    ]
  },
  "456": {
    "deal 1": [
      1
    ]
  },
  "666": {
    "deal 3": [
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, we go over the multidimensional array and change the hotel_id.

```
<?php
$array = array (
    0 =>
        array (
            'hotel_id'   => 123,
            'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
            'deal_name'  => 'deal 1',
            'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
            'end_date'   => '2017-12-10',
            'plan'       => 'B/B',
        ),
    1 =>
        array (
            'hotel_id'   => 456,
            'hotel_name' => 'hotel 2',
            'deal_name'  => 'deal 1',
            'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
            'end_date'   => '2017-12-07',
            'plan'       => 'H/B',
        ),
    2 =>
        array (
            'hotel_id'   => 123,
            'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
            'deal_name'  => 'deal 1',
            'start_date' => '2018-01-05',
            'end_date'   => '2017-02-12',
            'plan'       => 'H/B',
        ),
    3 =>
        array (
            'hotel_id'   => 666,
            'hotel_name' => 'hotel 3',
            'deal_name'  => 'deal 3',
            'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
            'end_date'   => '2017-12-30',
            'plan'       => 'B/B',
        ),
    4 =>
        array (
            'hotel_id'   => 123,
            'hotel_name' => 'hotel 1',
            'deal_name'  => 'deal 3',
            'start_date' => '2017-12-01',
            'end_date'   => '2017-12-30',
            'plan'       => 'B/B',
        ),
);

$hotelDeals = array();

foreach ($array as $recordKey => $dealData) {
    $hotelId = $dealData['hotel_id'];
    if (!isset($hotelDeals[$hotelId])) {
        $hotelDeals[$hotelId] = array();
    }
    $dealName = $dealData['deal_name'];
    if (!isset($hotelDeals[$hotelId][$dealName])) {
        $hotelDeals[$hotelId][$dealName] = array ($recordKey);
    } else {
        $hotelDeals[$hotelId][$dealName][] = $recordKey;
    }
}

foreach ($hotelDeals as $hotelId => $deals) {
    foreach ($deals as $dealName => $recordKeys) {
        if (count($recordKeys) === 1) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($recordKeys as $recordKey) {
            $array[$recordKey]['hotel_id'] = $array[$recordKey]['hotel_id'] . '99';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello its exactly what i need , thank you very very much.